# Is there a way to specify the base address of a shared library using dlopen()?

Tags: dynamic-linking, dlopen

It seems that when we dlopen() some libraries, they will be loaded into some preferred (but not fixed) addresses. I've checked the source code of dlopen(), and a core function says

```
static __always_inline const char *
_dl_map_segments (struct link_map *l, int fd,
                  const ElfW(Ehdr) *header, int type,
                  const struct loadcmd loadcmds[], size_t nloadcmds,
                  const size_t maplength, bool has_holes,
                  struct link_map *loader)
{
  const struct loadcmd *c = loadcmds;
  if (__glibc_likely (type == ET_DYN))
    {
      /* This is a position-independent shared object.  We can let the
         kernel map it anywhere it likes, but we must have space for all
         the segments in their specified positions relative to the first.
         So we map the first segment without MAP_FIXED, but with its
         extent increased to cover all the segments.  Then we remove
         access from excess portion, and there is known sufficient space
         there to remap from the later segments.
         As a refinement, sometimes we have an address that we would
         prefer to map such objects at; but this is only a preference,
         the OS can do whatever it likes. */
      ElfW(Addr) mappref
        = (ELF_PREFERRED_ADDRESS (loader, maplength,
                                  c->mapstart & GLRO(dl_use_load_bias))
           - MAP_BASE_ADDR (l));
      /* Remember which part of the address space this object uses.  */
      l->l_map_start = (ElfW(Addr)) __mmap ((void *) mappref, maplength,
                                            c->prot,
                                            MAP_COPY|MAP_FILE,
                                            fd, c->mapoff);
      if (__glibc_unlikely ((void *) l->l_map_start == MAP_FAILED))
        return DL_MAP_SEGMENTS_ERROR_MAP_SEGMENT;
...
}
```

The comment says you can specify a preferred address, but OS will determine whether to use it.

Question

1. Is there any way we can specify the base address for each dlopened module?
2. `ELF_PREFERRED_ADDRESSS` is set to 0 by default, but this macro seems to infer that the preferred addresses can be changed, say by an environment variable? But even there is one, I doubt that it can be changed for each dlopened library.
3. If I want to implement this feature myself, it seems that I need to wrap a new dlopen function and pass the preferred address to the above core function (and use MAP_FIXED maybe). Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you solved that problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can specify the base address for each dlopened module?

No.

> ELF_PREFERRED_ADDRESSS is set to 0 by default, but this macro seems to infer that the preferred addresses can be changed, say by an environment variable? But even there is one, I doubt that it can be changed for each dlopened library.

This code is *compiled* into the dynamic loader `ld-linux.so` and can not be changed after the compilation.

> If I want to implement this feature myself, it seems that I need to wrap a new dlopen function and pass the preferred address to the above core function (and use MAP_FIXED maybe). Is it correct?

The function is *private* to `ld-linux`. You will not be able to wrap it, or call it from outside of `ld-linux`.

P.S. What you are *likely* looking for is the [prelink](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Prelink) command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I understand that the core function of dlopen is private to ld-linux. The way of "wrapping" actually means that I could modify the source code of ld-linux and recompile a new ld-linux.so. Is it a feasible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I've also quickly checked the prelink technique, which seems to be useful, except our project needs to be highly flexible, i.e., we cannot pre-load the modules in/before the linking time, but have to input the modules' name and decide which one (and where) will be loaded into the binary.

Comment: @HaoLi Please edit your question with the _actual_ requirements you have. Otherwise we are solving the http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I posted the patch set to glibc that implements this feature: https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2023-May/148241.html

It implements many other features in this area, for
example you can set the relocation address for every
dependency solib too. And actually it allows much
more than that. It is fully documented in the patch
cover letter, together with my use-case of that.

Unfortunately it seems difficult to
get any attention from glibc devs unless many people
need a new API. So unless more people will express
their need for this in glibc mail list, it will likely
remain ignored forever.